# Ajax call after redirect page

Tags: jquery

Is their a way to redirect a page with javascript and then directly do a ajax call that adds data to that page:

Following doesn't work (*#application_search_result is a tag from the redirecturl page*):

```
function searchApplication(element, event){
    //URL
    var redirectUrl = '/feeds/application_search.php';
    var url = '/feeds/lib/auto_suggest_application_search.php';

    //Redirect page 
    window.location = redirectUrl;

    //Ajax call
    $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        data: {
            "search": element.value.trim().replace(/ /g,"+")
        },
        success: function(result){
            $("#application_search_result").html(result);                    
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: write `ajax` code in `redirected page` so it work, on same page will be redirect and no other script will execute

Comment: Add onLoad event to redirect page and do an ajax call when onLoad event fires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it looks like if you want first to search something and then display the search results in a page? If so you could do something like I did  with a hidden Submit Form and passing the Results as Json to the PHP File:

This is my search Function:

```
function search(term) {
    if (term !== "" && term !== null && term !== "undefined") {
        swal({
            title: 'Search for ' + term,
            onOpen: function() {
                swal.showLoading();

                ... some code from me

                $.when(ajaxCall('search', params)).done(function(searchresult) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        swal.close();

                        if (searchresult) {
                            searchPOSTcall(searchresult);
                        } else {
                            swal({
                                type: 'error',
                                title: 'Nothing found!',
                            })
                        }
                    }, 500);
                });
            },
        })
    }
}
```

As you can see I make a Ajax Call to my Search Function which returns Search Results. If Im getting some Results I pass them to the important function which "fakes" a Form Submit:

```
function searchPOSTcall(params) {
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("method", "post");
        form.setAttribute("action", "/forecast");

        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "searchresult");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", JSON.stringify(params));

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    }
```

Its important to do a `JSON.stringify` with your search results to avoid many errors.
And then in your Results.php File you can get the results like this:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['searchresult'])) {
        $result = json_decode($_POST['searchresult']);
        ... do something with your results
    }
?>
```

Hope this will help you to slove your problem.

EDIT:

As mentioned in the comments you could just do an ajax call in your result.php with `onLoad` or something. Use my method only if you want to check first if there are any search results and then pass them to the result page and if nothing is found stay on the page where you started the search. This avoids an unnecessary redirect to the result page if there are no results.